# Node Red container and serial port of MacOs

Tags: docker, macos, arduino, serial-port, node-red

I try to connect my Arduino on MacOS to a node-red docker container using serial port, but it doesn't work. Someone has a solution for this ?
I use this docker-compose file:

```
networks:
  node-red:

services:
  nodered:
    image: nodered/node-red
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./public:/home/nol/node-red-static
    links:
      - mongodb:mongodb
    networks:
      - node-red
    user: root
    devices:
      - "/dev/cu.usbmodem101"
    group_add:
      - dialout
```

[image: Error on the terminal]

The name of my port:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because docker actually runs in a virtual machine on MacOS so you will need to map the serial port into the virtual machine first so it can then be mounted into the container.

The following gist may help: https://gist.github.com/stonehippo/e33750f185806924f1254349ea1a4e68

It explains how to map the serial port into the VM as a virtual USB serial port when using a version of Docker that uses VirtualBox.

If you are on a new M1 Mac then it may not be currently be possible:

https://github.com/moby/hyperkit/issues/149

Comment: I use new Mac M1 :'(

Comment: I'm looking at a similar question to this; is it possible to [edit] this answer to include the details in the answer itself, rather than just have a link to an external resource?